# after installation it does not appear

Tags: installation, 13.04

I've installed 13.04 by USB drive, It is successfully installed but when I restarted, PC does not show the option to choose ubuntu, it directly loads windows-7. How to get rid of this...?

Comment: It is becaus `Ubuntu Grub Menu` didn't installed well..

Answer (score 1):

**Here is your solution:**

I prefer you to use Ubuntu Grub Menu, that is let Ubuntu to allow you to chose which OS you want to boot (Windows or Ubuntu).

Here are the steps that would help you..

Boot from your Ubuntu LiveCD/DVD or Ubuntu bootable USB and select 'Try Ubuntu' (not 'Install Ubuntu'). When Ubuntu starts open terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

Installing boot-repair ( a good s/w to fix grub ):

```
    $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install boot-repair
    Run boot-repair from your system or type: (boot-repair &) in terminal
```

When started select Option 'Recommended Repair' from out of two options:

'Recommended Repair' & 'Advanced Options'.

Follow very easy onscreen instruction, it will build/fix your grub menu..

Restarting your system may list all the Operating Systems installed in your HDD.
Be sure that you have properly shut down Windows 8, before starting these steps..

You can get more help on - [Using Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)